How to set time interval between automatic calculations in Excel
I have a spreadsheet which source data from external sources and many formulas depends on these source data. The source data are updating frequently (sub-second), but my spreadsheet is too heavy to respond to that if the formula option is set to be automatic. So is there any way to set a time interval to the automatic calculation, say 10 minutes, so every 10 minutes the spreadsheet will re-calculate all the formulas?
Adding another twist, if user enters a number, then the spreadsheet gets updated instantly for those formulas relies on the changed cells?
Is this too much to ask for?

y not just disable automatic calculation in excel options, then just 'recalculate' on demand. (press F9 to calculate)
